# Draw a Fibonacci Network!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, fibonacci

## What are Fibonacci networks?

> In 1202, an Italian mathematician known as Fibonacci posed the following problem:
>
> "A male and a female rabbit are born at the beginning of the year. We assume the following conditions:
>
> 1.After reaching the age of two months, each pair produces a mixed pair, (one male, one female), and then another mixed pair each month thereafter.
>
> 2.No deaths occur during the year."
>
> How many rabbits will there be at the end of the year?

[image: Fibonacci rabbits]

[Sources for graph and problem statement](http://aix1.uottawa.ca/%7Ejkhoury/fibonacci.htm)

## Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program/function to draw an ASCII art to output or a text file, or a graphical picture to a file/screen of a graph with following settings:

1. At 0th tick, there is one newly-born node.
2. Every newly born node creates a normal node after one tick after being born and gets deactivated.
3. A normal node creates a normal node and a newly-born node one tick after its birth and gets deactivated.

Your program will get the non-negative value `n` as input, and will draw the graph at the `n`th tick. Note that your program can draw newly-born nodes and normal nodes differently, but this is not necessary.

## Rules

- You must not use any built-in Fibonacci sequence function or mathematical constants or similar.
- If your program outputs to a file, it must be either a text file in a suitable and viewable format and encoding, or an image file in a suitable and viewable format with recognizable colors (for example, an image format that can be uploaded to SE).
- Your program can draw graph in any size, any shape and any alignment but the nodes and connections must be recognizable. Tree-shaped graphs (like the graph in "What are Fibonacci networks?" section) are recommended, but not necessary.
- Common code golf rules apply to this challenge.

## Examples

```
Input: 2
Possible Output: 
*
|
*
| \
* *

Input: 0
Possible Output: 
*
```

> Input: 5
>
> Possible Graphical Output:[image: Diagram in PNG]

This is a [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf). Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: Can you have a larger testcase?

Comment: @LeakyNun Well, every time i draw , i notice that i've drawn something wrong ... I'm trying hard to draw a larger test case ...

Comment: Then draw a larger testcase before uploading.

Comment: @LeakyNun http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9681/17602

Comment: @GLASSIC To draw the large test case, why not just write an ungolfed version of your challenge and run it?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix I haven't solved it yet . I've made graph system already but i'm still trying to write an algorithm to generate the ascii art ... (I'm not a good programmer , nor a good codegolfer)

Comment: @GLASSIC according to your own challenge, output as an image is allowable. Couldn't you use that, at least for now?

Comment: I've started on this challenge. The mind boggles when you get past the first few months.

Comment: @Polyducks Yes. That is very true.

Comment: I think I've got it. You can draw it as modular pieces and change the scale as you go further down.

Comment: I've got a partial answer which would help other people. Should I post it and update as I fix it up? I'm not sure what the rules are for answers in this stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

```
Ms+0m+Wd+J+G"| "+G1+\-gJtd_UHgb
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ms%2B0m%2BWd%2BJ%2BG%22%7C+%22%2BG1%2B%5C-gJtd_UHgb&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6)

#### How it works

```
M                                  def g(G, H):
    m                     _UH        map for d in [H - 1, …, 0]:
         J+G"| "                       assign J = G + "| "
        +       +G1                    J + G + 1
     +Wd                               conditional +, if d is truthy (nonzero):
                   +\-gJtd               "-" + g(J, d - 1)
  +0                                 prepend 0
 s                                   concatenate
                             gbQ   g("\n", input)
```

#### Output for 6

```
0
| 
1-0
| | 
| 1-0
| | | 
| | 1-0
| | | 
| | 1
| | 
| 1-0
| | | 
| | 1
| | 
| 1-0
| | 
| 1
| 
1-0
| | 
| 1-0
| | | 
| | 1
| | 
| 1-0
| | 
| 1
| 
1-0
| | 
| 1-0
| | 
| 1
| 
1-0
| | 
| 1
| 
1-0
| 
1
```

## Pyth, 43 bytes

```
Mc+WH`G++WG\-+j"
| "g0tH"
`-"j"
  "g1tHbjg0
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Mc%2BWH%60G%2B%2BWG%5C-%2Bj%22%0A%7C+%22g0tH%22%0A%60-%22j%22%0A++%22g1tHbjg0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6)

#### Output for 6

```
0-1-0-1-0-1-0
  |   |   `-1
  |   `-1-0-1
  |     `-1-0
  |       `-1
  `-1-0-1-0-1
    |   `-1-0
    |     `-1
    `-1-0-1-0
      |   `-1
      `-1-0-1
        `-1-0
          `-1
```

Answer (score 5):

## HTML5/JavaScript, 1262 bytes

This is my code which displays a Fibonacci network. You can just paste it into a file with a name like `index.html` and run it in your favourite browser (I only tested Chrome and Firefox though). When you launch it, it asks you for the desired number of generations. It uses the HTML5 `<canvas>` tag to display the image.

```
<script>let t,p,o,c=[],q=50,r=20,s=25;function d(o){return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));}function e(a,x,y){o.beginPath();o.fillStyle=a?"red":"#000";o.arc(x*q+s,y*q+s,r,0,2*3.14159);o.fill();}function f(a,b,c,d){o.beginPath();o.strokeStyle="blue";o.lineWidth=3;o.moveTo(a*q+s,b*q+s);o.lineTo(c*q+s,d*q+s);o.stroke();}function g(i){return c[i].a+c[i].c;}function h(i){return c[i].b+c[i].d;}function k(j,e,f,b,n,x,y,z){f=j;b=0;while(1){if(!e){f.t=g(t);f.u=0;f.v=f.t;f.w=f.b;}else{n=t-b+1;x=t-b;z=e.b%2?(g(n)+g(x)+1):(-(g(n)+h(x)+1));f.t=e.v+z;f.u=e.w+1;f.v=f.t;f.w=f.u+f.b;}if(!f.a)break;b+=f.b+1;e=f;f=f.z;}return {a:f.b==0,x:f.v,y:f.w};}function l(j,c,b){b=k(j);f(b.x,b.y,c.x,c.y);e(b.a,b.x,b.y);return b;}function m(j){while(j.a)j=j.z;return j;}function n(j,o,p,q,r,s){if(o>t)return;q=l(j,p);r=d(j);m(r).b++;n(r,o+1,q);if(m(j).b>0){r=d(j);s=m(r);s.a=!0;s.z={a:!1,b:0};n(r,o+1,q);}}function b(i,z,y){t=parseInt(prompt());if(isNaN(t)||t<0)t=0;p=document.getElementById("o");c.push({a:0,b:0,c:0,d:0,e:1});for(i=1;i<t+1;i++){z=c[c.length-1];y={a:(i>1?i%2:0)+z.c,b:(i>1?1-i%2:0)+z.d,c:z.a+z.c,d:z.b+z.d};y.e=y.a+y.b+y.c+y.d;c.push(y);}p.width=q*(c[c.length-1].e+1);p.height=q*(t+1);o=p.getContext("2d");n({a:!1,b:0},0,0);}</script><body onload="b()"><canvas id="o">
```

An example for 6 generations would be this one:
[image: The Fibonacci network after 6 generations]

As you can see, newly born nodes are colored in red, the others are black.

For reference, this is my ungolfed, development code that does exactly the same:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fibonacci Graph</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   let totalGenerations;
   let canvas, ctx;
   let individualCount = [];
   let individualDrawSize = 50, individualDrawRadius = 20, individualDrawOffset = 25;
  
   function generateIndividualCount()
   {
    individualCount.push(
    {
     babiesL: 0,   //number of babies on the left side of the main individual
     babiesR: 0,
     adultsL: 0,
     adultsR: 0,
     total: 1   //total number of individuals (sum of all other members+1, because the main individual counts as well)
    });
    
    for(let i=1; i<totalGenerations+1; i++)
    {
     let last = individualCount[individualCount.length - 1];
     let next =
     {
      //make an adult alternate between having a baby at the left and the right side (right side first)
      babiesL: (i>1 ? i%2 : 0) + last.adultsL,
      babiesR: (i>1 ? 1-i%2 : 0) + last.adultsR,
      adultsL: last.babiesL + last.adultsL,
      adultsR: last.babiesR + last.adultsR
     };
     next.total = next.babiesL + next.babiesR + next.adultsL + next.adultsR;
     individualCount.push(next);
    }
   }
   
   function setupContext()
   {
    canvas.width = individualDrawSize * (individualCount[individualCount.length - 1].total + 1);
    canvas.height = individualDrawSize * (totalGenerations + 1);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   }
   
   function deepCopy(obj)
   {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
   }

   function drawIndividual(isBaby, x, y)
   {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = isBaby ? "red" : "black";
    ctx.arc(x*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset, y*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset, individualDrawRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
   }
   
   function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
   {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.moveTo(x1*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset, y1*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(x2*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset, y2*individualDrawSize + individualDrawOffset);
    ctx.stroke();
   }

   function getIndividualCountLeft(i)  //left like in "the opposite of right"
   {
    return individualCount[i].babiesL + individualCount[i].adultsL;
   }
   
   function getIndividualCountRight(i)
   {
    return individualCount[i].babiesR + individualCount[i].adultsR;
   }
   
   function getPosition(ancestorInformation)
   {
    let prevInfo;
    let tempInfo = ancestorInformation;
    let currDepth = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
     if(prevInfo == undefined)
     {
      tempInfo.birthX = getIndividualCountLeft(totalGenerations);
      tempInfo.birthY = 0;
      
      tempInfo.givingBirthX = tempInfo.birthX;
      tempInfo.givingBirthY = tempInfo.ageAtGivingBirth;
     }
     else
     {
      let generationsLeftForParent = totalGenerations - (currDepth-1);
      let generationsLeftForChild = totalGenerations - currDepth;    //left like in "to go" or "There are 42 cookies left"
      let isLeftBranch = (prevInfo.ageAtGivingBirth % 2 == 0);
      let distanceToParent;
      
      
      if(isLeftBranch)
       distanceToParent = -(getIndividualCountLeft(generationsLeftForParent) + getIndividualCountRight(generationsLeftForChild) + 1);
      else
       //some of these directions may seem odd, but because the parent subtree begins with a left branch (and individualCount only contains data for trees beginning with a right branch), it needs to be inversed
       //if individualCount would have been generated for trees beginning with a left node, all of the getIndividualCountLeft/getIndividualCountRight function would need to be inversed
       //or, when individualCount would have been generated for both cases, functions like getIndividualCountRight_LeftBegin and getIndividualCountLeft_RightBegin could be used
       distanceToParent = getIndividualCountLeft(generationsLeftForParent) + getIndividualCountLeft(generationsLeftForChild) + 1;  //+1, because the previous value of distanceToParent is just the number of empty fields (on the x axis) between the parent and the child
      
      tempInfo.birthX = prevInfo.givingBirthX + distanceToParent;
      tempInfo.birthY = prevInfo.givingBirthY + 1;
      
      tempInfo.givingBirthX = tempInfo.birthX;
      tempInfo.givingBirthY = tempInfo.birthY + tempInfo.ageAtGivingBirth;
     }
     if(!tempInfo.isParent)
      break;
     currDepth += tempInfo.ageAtGivingBirth + 1;
     prevInfo = tempInfo;
     tempInfo = tempInfo.child;
    }
    
    return { isBaby: tempInfo.ageAtGivingBirth==0, x: tempInfo.givingBirthX, y: tempInfo.givingBirthY };
   }
   
   function draw(ancestorInformation, parentPos)
   {
    let pos = getPosition(ancestorInformation);
    drawLine(pos.x, pos.y, parentPos.x, parentPos.y);
    drawIndividual(pos.isBaby, pos.x, pos.y);
    return pos;
   }
   
   function getDeepestChild(ancestorInformation)
   {
    while(ancestorInformation.isParent)
     ancestorInformation = ancestorInformation.child;
    return ancestorInformation;
   }
   
   function drawAll(ancestorInformation, depth, parentPos)
   {
    if(depth > totalGenerations)
     return;
    
    let pos = draw(ancestorInformation, parentPos);
    let newAncestorInformation = deepCopy(ancestorInformation);
    getDeepestChild(newAncestorInformation).ageAtGivingBirth++;
    drawAll(newAncestorInformation, depth + 1, pos);
    
    if(getDeepestChild(ancestorInformation).ageAtGivingBirth > 0)
    {
     newAncestorInformation = deepCopy(ancestorInformation);
     let deepestChild = getDeepestChild(newAncestorInformation);
     deepestChild.isParent = true;
     deepestChild.child = { isParent: false, ageAtGivingBirth: 0 };
     drawAll(newAncestorInformation, depth + 1, pos);
    }
   }
  
   function load()
   {
    totalGenerations = parseInt(prompt("Number of generations?"));
    if(isNaN(totalGenerations)  ||  totalGenerations < 0)
     totalGenerations = 0;
    canvas = document.getElementById("output");
    generateIndividualCount();
    setupContext();
    drawAll({ isParent: false, ageAtGivingBirth: 0 }, 0, 0);     //although this individual does not really give birth after it has been born, it still has an attribute called "ageAtGivingBirth" (like its parents) to achieve a similar effect
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="load()">
  <canvas id="output" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px" width="1200" height="600">Canvas not supported...</canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```